# Git: Local and 'dead' copy of repo with repo ID

Tags: git, github

I'm wanting to:

1) Clone the repo

2) Save it's current repo ID (maybe to a text file?)

3) Then disconnect it from anything Git so that it won't change with time (crucial step)

Thanks!

Comment: git repository will not automatically update itself. Why would you want to "disconnect" it?

Comment: It's important that I know what version of the code was executed.  The code will only be executed once.

Comment: What is a "repo ID"?

Comment: Maybe it's called the repo version?  Some way to determine exactly what version of the code is being used.

Answer (score 1):

I'll step through your list of steps; but I'm going to be working mostly from your comment:

> It's important that I know what version of the code was executed. The code will only be executed once.

That's because most of your question seems to be an attempt to think up a procedure that meets this requirement, but unfortunately it isn't grounded in an understanding of git.

So,

> 1) Clone the repo

Fine, no issues here.

> 2) Save it's current repo ID (maybe to a text file?)

A "repo ID" is not a thing known to git.  From your comment about what you're trying to do, I think you mean you want to capture an identifier for the specific state of the repo at this time.  In my opinion what you want is the commit ID of the version you will have checked out when you run.

You say you need to know what version of the code ran, and I take that to mean you need to be able to reproduce the exact set of source code.  You actually could do that from a `TREE` ID.  But a `COMMIT` ID implies a `TREE` ID, and also preserves the commit metadata (authorship info, comment, placement in project history) - and more importantly, it's the ID you can most easily find and work with using typical user-facing git command syntax.

This does still stop short of capturing the entire state of the repo, but understanding *how* it stops short is important to what I'll say about item 3 on your list.  What you won't get out of the `COMMIT` ID is the state of the refs in the repository.

Now, at most one of the refs kinda-sorta matters, because probably you have a branch checked out (I'd guess `master`) and the version of code you run happens to be the version identified by the commit at the tip of that branch.  But once you've captured the `COMMIT` ID, that's that.  The branch could move on, and it wouldn't matter.  Where other branches or tags might have pointed (or might point in the future) certainly doesn't matter.  None of those things affect the state of the code at the moment you ran it.

You can get the current `COMMIT` ID by running `git show`; or if you want to see *only* the `COMMIT` ID, you could say `git log -n1 --format='%H'`.  Provided your work tree is clean and contains no untracked files, this fully describes the state of the code.  (If you *do* have uncommitted changes and/or untracked files, you'd need to capture that knowledge separately.  The simplest thing, if you need to know the exact state of the work tree, would be if you can have the work tree fully committed.)

> 3) Then disconnect it from anything Git so that it won't change with time (crucial step)

First of all, what does "disconnect it from anything Git" mean?  Do you mean disconnect it from a remote repository on github?  Or do you mean that you don't even want it to remain locally aware that it's a git repo?

"Disconnecting" from the remote isn't very meaningful.  You can change your local configuration to "forget" what remote it came from; but it's not like that remote is going to push changes to you anyway.

Taking the code out of source control is counter-productive to your goal of always being able to identify and recover this specific version of the code.  The `COMMIT` ID has meaning because the content is in git.

Well, whichever you mean, you say that "disconnecting" from git is crucial so that you can know this version of the code doesn't change.  The thing is, the meaning of the `COMMIT` ID that I recommended in step 2 *can never change anyway*.  That ID will *always* mean exactly that version of the code, no matter what.

By nature git isn't all that "connected" to start with.  Almost every operation runs locally.  As a matter of configuration, most people have it "remember" where an upstream repo is located; but this is just for convenience and only certain commands cause communication with that remote repository.

If you never run `git fetch` (or `git pull`, which does a fetch behind the scenes), then you'll never receive changes from the other repo.

Even if you run `git fetch`, this doesn't change any of your local refs.  You would have to ask for them to change, either by doing a `pull` to incorporate changes from the remote, or a `merge` to incorporate arbitrary changes, or a `rebase` or some other history-rewriting operation that forcefully relocates the ref, or create a new commit locally.

And even if you *did* do those things, it would never change the meaning of that commit ID you captured back in step 2.  If you changed things so that the commit containing the code you ran is "unreachable" from all refs in the repo, then eventually the commit could be lost; so don't do that.  The easiest way to not do that is to create a local tag or branch that points to that commit.  But even in the worst case, where you render the commit unreachable and it falls off the reflogs (which by default takes at least a month) and the commit is lost to you... even in this totally avoidable scenario, *still* the captured `COMMIT` ID can never refer to any *other* version of the code.

Why is that?  Well, it's because the `COMMIT` ID has 160 bits of information that are related to the underlying content in a way that might as well be random for our purposes.  Change anything that's used to calculate the ID, and you cause a new - for our purpose essentially random - ID to be chosen from a pool of 2^160.  The notation 2^160 is deceptively concise; that number is huge.  There is no practical chance of an ID recurring; certainly not within the evolution of a single codebase (but really... not ever).

And the way the ID is composed, that ultimately means that if you change one byte of one file anywhere in the working tree and generate a new commit from that, you will get a new and distinct ID.

So the `COMMIT` ID is the best concise way to validate that you're looking at the correct version of the code, and keeping the code in a git repo is the way to preserve the `COMMIT` ID's meaning, and nothing git does is ever going to change the meaning of the `COMMIT` ID.  Done and done, there is no crucial need to "disconnect" in whatever sense of the word.